Azure b2c still authenticated after hitting logout
I'm implementing Azure B2C with an ASP.NET MVC app on .NET 4.8. Our process uses cookie authentication and local user accounts with a custom flow policy, which works great.
The issue is that I am having trouble signing out of Azure B2C. Currently I'm testing locally and a user click the "Sign Out" button. The signout button clears the local data, and then redirects to the link via this document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect?ref=blog.bajonczak.com#send-a-sign-out-request
The link appears to work successfully, but when I click the "Back" button in my browser, the user is still authenticated through B2C.
Can anyone tell me if this is the correct way to sign out of B2C?
Sign in code through Startup
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        // ASP.NET web host compatible cookie manager
        CookieManager = new SystemWebChunkingCookieManager(),
        CookieName = "MyPortal.AuthCookie",
        CookieSameSite = Microsoft.Owin.SameSiteMode.Lax,
        CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
        CookieHttpOnly = true,
        CookiePath = Globals.ApplicationRelativePath
    });

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // Generate the metadata address using the tenant and policy information
            MetadataAddress = String.Format(Globals.WellKnownMetadata, Globals.TenantId, Globals.DefaultPolicy),

            // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
            ClientId = Globals.ClientId,
            RedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = Globals.PostLogoutRedirectUri,
            UseTokenLifetime = true,

            // Add the ProtocolValidator property here
            // Specify the callbacks for each type of notifications
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                SecurityTokenValidated = OnSecurityTokenValidated
            },

            // Specify the claim type that specifies the Name property.
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name",
                RoleClaimType = "extension_Role",
                ValidateIssuer = false
            },

            // Specify the scope by appending all of the scopes requested into one string (separated by a blank space)
            Scope = $"openid profile offline_access {Globals.ReadTasksScope} {Globals.WriteTasksScope}",

            // ASP.NET web host compatible cookie manager
            CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager(),
        }
    );
}

Log off function - added OWIN sign out for extra checks but it does the same thing regardless
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    // Log out through OWIN 
    IEnumerable<AuthenticationDescription> authTypes = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes();
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(authTypes.Select(t => t.AuthenticationType).ToArray());

    Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes();
    HttpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(string.Empty), null);

    // Expire cookie
    if (Request.Cookies["MyPortal.AuthCookie"] != null)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie("MyPortal.AuthCookie");
        authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
        Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
    }

    try
    {
        AccountManager accountManager = new AccountManager();
        accountManager.LogOff();

        var RequestUri = new System.Uri(Globals.AadLogoutUrl);
        return Redirect(RequestUri.ToString());
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}

Finally - my RequestURI
https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{flow}/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={redirectURI}

The User Identity repopulates itself when clicking back, opening a new tab or visiting the page again, or even opening a fresh browser and visiting the page. (all while the current browser still is open)

This is what it looks like when I hit the Index of the MVC site again.


I've been wrapping my head around this for awhile and haven't found a solution, other than a pretty hacky one.
My setup is azure b2c, .NET 4.8, IIS 8.5 implementation. My signout appeared to work with my above code but when I could visit the session again in the same browser, or click the back button, the user was still logged in.
The below code is what gets hit when the user opens a browser or hits a back button. It starts a new session and then the existing user is set to NULL, instead of an empty string and the cookies are present. Clearing the claims from the user and the cookies in this block of code cleared it.
This is still a very hacky solution so I'm looking for another solution that is more sustainable.
protected void Session_start()
{
    // starting a session and already authenticated means we have an old cookie
    var existingUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
    if (existingUser != null && existingUser.Identity.Name != "")
    {
        // clear any existing cookies
        IAuthenticationManager authMgr = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        authMgr.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        //manually clear user from HttpContext so Authorize attr works
        HttpContext.Current.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());
    }

}


It could be one of two things.
1. User Session
Although you have invalidated the cookie, there will likely still be an in-memory session on the server.
In your LogOff action, clear the session to remove it from memory.
Session.Clear()

2. Browser Cache
When you click the back button, depending on what browser you're using, you might simply have cached content displayed. This may appear as though you're signed in, but refreshing the page, or retyping your web app's address, will often produce different results.
Your post-logout redirect URI should always be set to a clean state route or action on your controller. For example, to a post-logout https://your-app.com/signedOut where you can perhaps redirect to the home page, and optionally display a logged out message for a few seconds.

#1 seems to be more likely. I tried Session.Abandon(); as well as Session.Clear and both arent solving the issue for me. I updated the post, you can definitely see the User Identity and Claim is empty after logout, but when I visit the page again, go to the back button, open a new tab and do the same they're still logged in.

Can you use network capture in browser developer tools to inspect the request being made to the server? Does it contain any cookies?

Yes it does, it has all the same cookies that I was clearing out before. The MyPortal.AuthCookie and the ASP.NET Session cookie both say Session and don't have an expiration on them.

@user1299379 Yeah I thought it might. Its cached im the browser. OAuth uses cryptographic signature verification, your app is treating the cookie as a legitimate new token: There is no token revocation process. In a normal flow, you would redirect to a post signout page and invalidate the cookie there. Just in case the browser is ignoring set-cookie in your invalidation based on it being empty,  try giving it some arbitrary value, or the old cookie value. See if that overwrites the cache.

My plot has thickened. I tested the above code with the cookie expiration by running it through debug locally. The logout worked and visiting the page again in the same browser required login again. My app is hosted on IIS so I'm investigating there to see if IIS is caching the cookies somewhere

@user1299379 Try capturing the response of the server after the logout button is pressed, and verify that the response has a set-cookie header with expires value less than current date. And do it for MyPortal.AuthToken and asp.net session.

I was able to get this to work but my solution feels very "hacky", See my update and I'm going to keep looking. As for your question, I did see that the Response passed back the cookies with expiration dates
